# Override Reading of HTTP Body with .net C# HTTPHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, httphandler, multipartform-data

Using C# I'd like to take control over the reading of the HTTP Requests from a POST.  Primarily to read the stream of a `multipart/form-data` file upload to track the stream as it's received from the client.

Using the `ProcessRequest` or the Async `BeginProcessRequest` the body has already been parsed by ASP.net / IIS.

Is there a way to override the built-in reading via a HTTPHandler, or will I have to use another mechanism?

Many thanks

Andy

**Update** - Added code example as requested, albeit no different to a normal class that's implemented IHttpHandler

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // The body has already been received by the server
        // at this point.  

        // I need a way to access the stream being passed 
        // from the Client directly, before the client starts 
        // to actually send the Body of the Request.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can capture the stream via the `context.BeginRequest` event of a HttpModule.

For example :

```
public class Test : IHttpModule
{

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(onBeginRequest);
    }


    public void onBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = (sender as HttpApplication).Context;
        if( context == nul ) { return; }

        if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("test-handler.ext"))
        {
            Logger.SysLog("onBeginRequest");
            TestRead(context);
        }

    }

    // Read the stream
    private static void TestRead(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream()))
        {
            Logger.SysLog("Start Read");
            reader.ReadToEnd();
            Logger.SysLog("Read Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

Really I was trying to avoid HttpModules, as they are processed for every .net request, so really I'd stil like to know how to do it via a HTTPHandler.

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely do that by implementing an IHttpHandler.

This [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET) will get you started. There is no need to override the built-in reading.
You receive all the data in the Request, and can process it as required.

Comment: I can't see any reference in that example to reading the Body directly from the client.  

It's no different to any other HttpHander the `InputStream` will already have buffered the body of the `POST`.  I want read the actual stream from the client, not allow IIS / .Net read the body.